# How is that possible that file was changed without date modification?

Tags: linux, centos, raid, storage-area-network

I'm using Blade Server with CentOS 6.5 (ext4) installed, disks combined in raid6, connected in a storage area network. Somehow some of my files become corrupted from time to time without updating the modification date information.

As I correctly understood it could be possible because of SAN errors. Could you please provide me with other reasons of the problem?

**EDIT:**

This question is a general question that doesn't need any specification about my environment. I just curious why it could be happened? If it is too complicated to answer, than ask specification you need I will provide it.

Comment: You likely have filesystem corruption. Talk with your storage administrator. You'll need to nuke this filesystem, create a new one, then restore from backup.

Comment: Just FYI, `touch` *can* modify files timestamps: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touch_(Unix)

Comment: This change wasn't made by a user. Any other suggestions?